# Probability density function of the mean of $n$ i.i.d random variables

Tags: random-variables, density-function

**Question**:

Assume that the $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are continuous **i.i.d** random variables. Calculate the probability density function of:

$$Y_n:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$

**My try**:

I thought maybe finding the CDF is easier. So I wrote:

$$\mathbb{P}(Y_n\le y)=\mathbb{P}(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\le y)$$

However, this gives me nothing. I do not know how to go further.

Comment: Here is a formula for the p.d.f of the sum of independent random variables: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Sums_of_independent_random_variables

Note that on that link the variables are not assumed to be i.i.d so actually all the p.d.f.s are the same in the case you are asking about. Thus the p.d.f of $Y_n$ is the convolution of the p.d.f of the $X_i$'s with itself $n-1$ times. I would write an answer if I understood convolutions better.

For general intuition, recall the Central Limit Theorem: as $n$ goes to infinity the distribution of $Y_n$ tends to normal.

Answer (score 1):

Let's $\varphi_X(t) = E(e^{itX})$ the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Definition) of $X$ (if the density function of $X$ is known, then $\varphi_X(t) = E(e^{itX}) = \int_{\Bbb R}e^{itx}f_X(x)dx$). Then

$$\varphi_Y(t)=E\left(e^{it\frac{1}{n}\sum X_i}\right)=\left(E\left(e^{i\frac{t}{n}X}  \right)  \right)^{n} = \varphi^n_X\left(\frac{t}{n}  \right)$$

Use the [inverse formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Inversion_formulae), we obtain the density function of $Y$
$$f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\Bbb R}e^{-ity}\varphi_Y(t)dt = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\Bbb R}e^{-ity}\varphi^n_X\left(\frac{t}{n}  \right)dt$$

Another representation without using characteristic function is

$$f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\Bbb R}e^{-ity}\varphi_Y(t)dt = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\Bbb R}e^{-ity}\left(  \int_{\Bbb R}e^{itx}f_X(x)dx\right)^ndt$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way to calculate this without the use of the "characteristic function"?

Comment: @AshtonMath This is the simplest way. Besides, using characteristic function is just a representation and we can use another representation by using the density function of $X$. I modiffy the answer to add the second representation.